# Building a container image using Podman gives Error: kernel does not support overlay fs:

Tags: containers, kernel, podman, buildah

While building a container image using Podman, I am facing the below error

```
time="2023-06-01T06:15:25Z" level=warning msg="\"/\" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers"
Error: kernel does not support overlay fs: unable to create kernel-style whiteout: operation not permitted
```

The build happens inside Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and
Podman version is 3.4.2

I tried changing the driver to overlay2 and ext4 but it did not work out. I tried to build using buildah but getting similar error there as well

```
storage.conf file

# Default Storage Driver, Must be set for proper operation.
driver = "overlay"

# Temporary storage location
runroot = "/run/containers/storage"

# Primary Read/Write location of container storage
graphroot = "/var/lib/containers/storage"

# Storage path for rootless users
#
# rootless_storage_path = "$HOME/.local/share/containers/storage"
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: maybe this:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689181/error-kernel-does-not-support-overlay-fs-overlay-is-not-supported-over-extfs